# Why does setting session variable in callback of geolocation.getCurrentPosition not work

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my meteor app I am trying to set user location first thing in

```
Meteor.startup(() => {...}
```

like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((succ) => Session.set('currentLocation',succ));
```

However, when trying to access this later in the app it returns an empty object. 
I validated setting a static session variable like 'hi', which works fine. I also validated that the callback gets called with console.log(succ), which also works fine. My best guess is some overwrite of the session variable is happening, I can't figure out how to test for that though.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could monkeypatch `Session.set` so it logs something when it's called, then you can see if it's being called somewhere else.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Are you suggesting to overwrite Session.set to also console.log its argument? what would that achieve?

Comment: Ohh I see ... could help with the debugging. Will try if that works.

Comment: Or you could just set a breakpoint in `Session.set`, and when it stops you can see where it's being called from. But that could get tedious if it's called a lot with unrelated session variables.

Comment: I really like the idea, because I think that's what a good programmer would do :) unfortunately I can't seem to figure out where Session.set is defined, which also makes it hard to set a brakepoint.

Comment: @FabianBosler just in case - Session is not persisted between refreshes. Meaning that if you set session variable and then reload the page - session will be empty. What happens if you add `console.log(Session.get('currentLocation'))` right after your session set?

Comment: I think we use `Meteor.startup` on server where we cannot access `Session` variables as Session variables are only available on the client side as per my knowledge.

Comment: I am at work right now, where I can't give this a try, but it appears Session only holds flat variables (is that the right term?), but getCurrentPositions returns an object. See Aboopallikaras answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Check This Article [Meteor Session](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html)

And Location Fetch Code is

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
 function success(position) { 
   Session.set("Latitude",position.coords.latitude);
   Session.set("Longitude",position.coords.longitude);

 }
 function error() {
    console.log("unable to retrive your location");
 }
```

And Retrive session data

```
 let Latitude = Session.get("Latitude");
 let Longitude = Session.get("Longitude");
```

Note:**Session Work Only Client Side**.

Comment: Awwww, so Session can only hold flat types and no objects?

Comment: Can confirm this works, could you elaborate a little more on the reason, why this is the case?

Comment: I meant to elaborate a little bit on what was the problem with my approach and why yours does work. That would be really helpful.